# Can't get Admob to show on multiple layouts?

Tags: java, android, xml, admob

I am trying to get Admob to display on my layout_one.xml and layout_two and can't get it to show. This app has a lot of swipe left and right and I want to display one ad over both layouts

Here are all my xml layouts:

activity_main.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/pager">
   </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

layout_one.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/relative_one"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:orientation="vertical">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Copy"
        android:id="@+id/Copy"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:onClick="onClickCopy"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/stringCopy"
    android:layout_above="@+id/Copy"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:gravity="left|top"
    android:background="#ffffff" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"/>
```

layout_two.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/relative_one"
android:background="#000000"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:orientation="vertical">


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Paste"
    android:id="@+id/Paste"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:onClick="onClickPaste"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/stringCopy"
    android:layout_marginBottom="71dp"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:gravity="left|top"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_above="@+id/Paste"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

   <!-- SHOULD I PUT ANOTHER ADVIEW IN THIS XML -->

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is all my java classes:

MainActivity.java

```
     public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

//View Pager
ViewPager viewpager;

//AdView
AdView adView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewpager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    PagerAdapter pAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewpager.setAdapter(pAdapter);

}


public void onClickCopy(View v)
{
    //Copy Text From layout_one to Clipboard

}

public void onClickPaste(View v)
{
    //Paste Text From Clipboard
}
   }
```

PagerAdapter.java

```
    public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {

    switch (arg0) {
        case 0:
            return new FragmentOne();
        case 1:
            return new FragmentTwo();

        default:
            break;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 2;
}
}
```

FragmentOne.java

```
    public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_one, container, false);
}
}
```

FragmentTwo.java

```
   public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_two, container, false);
}
}
```

Where would I put this code so that when they swipe between layout_one and layout_two that the same ad will be displayed and not make a new ad request every time they change views?

```
   //Display test Ads
    adView = new AdView(this);
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice("DEVICE_ID").build();
        adView.loadAd(request);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard pattern for doing this is to put your AdView either above or below your ViewPager and keep it static. That way you are not constantly requesting ads that you never get time to display.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:id="@+id/pager">
   </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
   <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="0"
     android:adUnitId="yourAdUnitId"
     android:id="@+id/adView">
</LinearLayout>
```

This way your Adview is outside your ViewPager and remains constant across all pages.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on what you mean by keeping AdView static. If possible can you please show some code on how you would achieve this based on the files provided?

Comment: I think that was meant to ordinary added banner in LinearLayout under ViewPager (code in the answer) Study Guides: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start

Comment: William I can't believe the fix was that simple and now everything works. I have been trying to get it to work for over 2 weeks and was overthinking the process to get the ads to show. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to cache Admob in scroll Grid View:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (position != adNum) {
            ...
            } else {
            if (mAdView == null) {
                frameLayout = new FrameLayout(mContext);
                mAdView = new AdView(mContext);

                ...

                frameLayout.addView(mAdView);
            } else {
                frameLayout.removeView(mAdView);
                frameLayout = new FrameLayout(mContext);
                frameLayout.addView(mAdView);
            }
            return frameLayout;
            }
}
```

[image]